# Why do you need to tag the repository of a CocoaPods podspec?

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoapods

[The CocoaPods Guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html#release) states the following:

> Once you have a release ready you'll ***need*** to make the corresponding tag.

Why is this necessary? Is it even necessary? Or can you get away with not tagging?

I figure it's because when you define a `.podspec`, you must specify a version: `0.0.1`, and Cocoapods can use that version to fetch the correct git commit.

For example, `s.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => s.version }`, where "tag" could maybe be left out and Cocoapods would manually assume the tag...

However, [you can specify the source](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source) of the library in various different ways that is *not* with a tag. So I would assume you do not ***need*** to tag.

Answer (score 1):

Tagging allows users and cocoapods to specify which version of the codebase they’d like to download.

Much the same as having software releases, tags let you easily reference commits to pull into your own codebase.

If no tag is specified in the podfile, cocoapods will pull the latest version specified in the podspec of the pod you’re pulling. Specifying the tag in the podfile is not required however it is required to be specified in the podspec.

Comment: "it is required to be specified in the podspec" - is that true? I'm not sure. I don't think there even is a way to specify a tag, unless you are stating the following: "there must be a tag corresponding to the version of the podspec." If you are referencing the tag in "s.source" then there doesn't need to be a tag..it can be a commit, or it can even be a ZIP file that's not a GitHub repository. So the question remains, MUST there be a tag created for each `.podspec`, and if so, why? And if there doesn't need to be then the documentation is a little misleading with the wording "need."